# The armature does not move with the mesh

Tags: rigging

Hy I am making a video game character and I'm on the animation part, specifically rigging. I am sure I did everything necessary and looked at similar questions to. As the title says the mesh does not move with the bones. Sorry, I'm used to 2D, but I REALLY want to get into 3D and know everything necessary to start except for rigging of course. The rigging part is hard and I don't know why.

[image: This is my issue that I am having difficulty with]

[image]

Comment: Hi, as first: armature should not move with mesh. Mesh should move with armature. This is very important diference. As second - if you give us link to your dropbox from your browser, it does not work. Upload image directly to your post and for .blend use:  http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add ling to your post also.

Comment: Hy, Thanks for the heads up, I added the pic and am just waiting for my .blend to upload

Comment: ok the .blend is there.

Answer (score 1):

your geometry is unsuitable for rigging. Imagine, that bones moving with vertexes. In your case is impossible bending mesh by bones correctly, because mesh have really bad topology for animation. And this is the reason why Blender can't assign vertexes to bones and give error message.

Normally you can use "Automatic weights" feature in Blender. Select mesh, press *"SHIFT+LMB"* select armature. After press *"CTRL+P"* assign mesh to bones. But this doesn't work in your case.

[image: Your case:]

This is how mesh **must** look for use in animation:
..as you can see, it work
[image]

You can control, how armature move with vertex by "Weight paint". Every bone have vertex group with the same name. Here you can set how strong are vertexes controlled by which bone.
[image]

I hope this help you. Also you can find a dozens tutorials about this theme all over the internet.

Comment: Hy, I appreciate this. Truth is I did not know that my mesh was terribly built and had bad topology. In fact I don't even know what that means so I will look it up. Thanks for the extra info to, I will be sure to keep this post in check. This really helped